# New tag request [sound-alike]

Tags: discussion

I ran across a suggested edit in the review queue for adding [sound-alike](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-alike) as a new tag.  [Here was the question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/26581/6957).  I rejected the edit, only so that we could have the discussion here first.

I do think having a tag for all those questions of the form "How do I create this sound?" is a good idea.  They're otherwise very difficult to search for.

So how about it?  Is [sound-alike](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-alike) the way to go?  Other suggestions for what to name that tag?  Do you dislike the idea altogether?

Comment: hi josh, it was my edit/addition of the tag (i saw no other appropriate way to add this tag). I hope the tag can stay, because it is self explanatory (i think). it is derived from 'lookalike', but you probably figured out that much :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the name 'sound-a-like'. It is too long, and it isn't something that I would say, or would occur to me while tagging a post. Since everything here is about sound design, we should look for tag names that don't use the word 'sound' in them.

Here are some ideas:

- replication
- duplication
- howdoi
- howdoi-request
- makethis or make-this
- makethissound or make-this-sound, which seems too long

Suggestions from the comments (feel free to post them in a standalone answer if you want 'credit'):

- mimic
- recreate

Comment: I'm pretty keen o replication or perhaps 'mimic', provided that 'mimic' doesn't have some other canonical meaning.

Comment: Seems tough to find something that gets the point across, yet still steers clear of the meta-tag, and *also* isn't super long!

Comment: Synth people tend to use the word 'recreate'.

Comment: replication and duplication are also used for other procedures (file/session duplication). that's why i coined 'sound-a-like', it has a unique meaning. howdoi is ok, but takes a second look (in my case at least).

Comment: there is another question by tobias schmidt [link](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26675/how-are-those-drums-on-lorde-royals-made) he uses the sound tag

Answer (score 2):

I like the term sound-alike and believe it should used. It is a common industry term, especially for production music libraries.

> ***Producer: "Sigur Ros won't let us use Gobbledigook in our Lexus ad, can you get us a sound alike?***

The term denotes, "I want it to evoke the same feeling and/or be recognized as similar to the example."

If the OP is asking, "How do I make my stuff sound just like this other guys?"  they are trying figure out how to approach their *[synth, guitar, gunshot, explosion, voice over, background ambience]* in order to achieve the same sonic quality as the example that they are referring to.

But these questions are a slippery slope. I draw the line, and will down-vote / comment / flag a sound-alike post for review, when the OP is looking to be spoon-fed a plug-in preset that allows them to achieve their desired result.